# What are the maximum limits for open files and running processes in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, high-load

I am deploying a highly loaded system on a cluster of centos servers. For stable operation of the system, I need to increase the limit of the maximum number of open files and processes. I started searching the forums and saw that some people set the limit to 65355, but then I found that some people set the limit to 500000.

What are the maximum limits in centos? Or maybe there is some optimal value at which the system will work best?

Answer (score 0):

You can set using sysctl. `sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000` and verify using `sysctl fs.file-max`